# How To check whether the page is served through xcache?

Tags: xcache

How can I check whether my wordpress site use Xcache to cache its content? How to verify it? Can't use the xcache admin because I also have a forum using ipboard. That forum use xcache. So, the xcache admin always show some usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xcache is an opcode accelerator it does not cache content. (Varnish, nginx or similar would do that) There is an admin page to get statistics on it. See http://xcache.lighttpd.net/wiki/InstallAdministration#HowtoInstallXCacheAdministrationPage

Comment: So how to make sure its working?